# How can i ADD directory using dockerfile from remote repository to current host?

Tags: docker, openshift, dockerfile

I'm using the following command in my docker file for OpenShift, unix terminal, trying to copy directory "test" to the container that i build, under "/apps/" directory:

```
ADD https://stash.abc.com:2000/dir_name/repos/test /apps/test/
```

The result is that it creates a file named "test" under a new directory "/apps/test/".

I also tried:

```
ADD https://stash.abc.com:2000/dir_name/repos/test/* /apps/test/
```

And this:

```
ADD https://stash.abc.com:2000/dir_name/repos/test /apps/
```

Which resulted in created file named "*"

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: There are no "directories" in the HTTP-Protocol.

Comment: @tkausl so is there other way to get a folder containing files from a bitbucket repository?

Comment: Use ``RUN`` to run a command which downloads files you need using ``curl`` or ``wget``.